# OR Statement for Advanced Filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking to find a way to filter two different columns.  Normally I would just use the filter for this, but the catch is that after filtering by one item the second filter is not possible as none of the remaining items have the desired value in the other column.  Is it possible to use an OR statement to filter two columns if 'a' appears in column A OR 'b' appears in column B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a third "helper" column that concatenates the 2 columns you're interested in.  Then, apply your "OR" filtering logic to the helper column, like this:

[image]